# Многопоточность для бота в телеграме

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, telebot

При одновременном использовании бота разными людьми, он работает поочередно.
С начала обрабатывает запрос одного, после второго.
Если это простые команды, то этого не заметно, но есть команды, в которые прописаны скрипты для выполнения, и вот пока от этот скрипт не отработает, другую команду не захавает.
Бот на питоне.

Как подогнать код под все запросы которые у меня есть, для одновременного их использования разным количеством людей?
ВАЖНО: Должно работать для библиотеки pytelegrambotAPI
ВАЖНО(2):Код запускается локально на компьютере не на сервере
ВАЖНО(3): Все возможные решения НЕ были предназначены для именно той библиотеки в которой я работаю(pytelegrambotAPI)

Comment: Без примеров кода Вам врядли кто то поможет

Answer (score 4):

Вот возьмем к примеру такой декоратор

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
pool = Pool(20)

def executor(fu):
    def run(*a,**kw):
        pool.apply_async(fu, a, kw, lambda result: pass, lambda error: raise error)
    return run
```

pool запустит 20 потоков

Теперь добавим

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
@executor
def send_welcome(message):
    time.sleep(5)
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

теперь каждая команда будет выполняться в одном из потоков пула - одновременно исполняется 20 команд.